# ADF table from View Object without backend Database

Tags: java, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

For a project, I need to create a table to read the data from user in UI..and just need to create an XML document from these values which I want  to do via calling a method...there is no back end DB for this...

What I have done is create a Entity object without existing Schema Object and created an view object from that Entity object....
But when I am running it, it gives an error..."View or table does not exist"..

What is wrong with this approach? or can anyone suggest me a better approach for this..

Comment: Do you want to manipulate (add, delete, sort, ...) the data or just show it to the user?

Comment: EO are BC Components used to map a DB object (such as tables or views) . So, if it is not backed by a table it shouldn't work. Why don't you try to store the inserted values into a Map ?

Comment: yes i want to edit those fields and want to expose the columns of tables in a java class...

Answer (score 0):

EOs represent a table in the database. So, as Endrik said,  if you have no table you do not need an EO. You want a programatic VO. Try [here](http://adfpractice-fedor.blogspot.com/2011/01/adf-bc-programmatically-populated-vo.html).

Comment: Endrick...  how to map them with the map...any link if u can suggest